# popen fails when called after seteuid(0)

Tags: c, linux, security, setuid

My C code does a

```
 seteuid (euid);
 popen("/root/bin/iptables ....", "r");
```

and it fails even if I call with seteuid(0). (The executables has setuid on).

It seems that seteuid and popen do not work together.

When popen called it prints in stderr the following msg

```
iptables v1.4.6: can't initialize iptables table : Permission denied (you must be root)
```

In other words popen "succeeds", but because a new shell is created the permissions are not maintained and the use case fails.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: What is the error? How does it fail?

Comment: You don't check the return code of seteuid, so what gives **popen("/usr/bin/who am i", "r");** you?

Comment: @JörgBeyer seteuid works well. I use the same mechanism to bind a port number < 1024. The problem here is popen.

Comment: try using `setuid()` -- iptables might not like running with euid != ruid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are invoking a setuid script by calling popen.  Many distibutions of Linux, for example, have checks in shell invocation to prevent a script begin run setuid or seteuid.  The problem is not popen, is is /bin/sh, which is the default shell popen uses.  In Linux /bin/sh is normally bash.

I believe it calls getresuid() and checks the saved uid, which has to be root.

You can work around this by calling an exec function  to a shell that does not perform these checks, or writing all of your code in C (no shell calls) - which is the real intent of the security check.